# Forwarding bluetooth remote input through a phone to a PC

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth remote which I can pair with my android phone.
I know it's not really possible to turn a phone into a bluetooth dongle, but is there any way I can forward the input the phone receives from the remote to a PC (e.g. remote's cursor keys) via an app or maybe by using adb?